# How to mean center and z-score data using R?

Tags: r

I was reading a paper and found that the authors calculated a score of a gene signature (composed of many genes) **for each sample** based on the following steps: 1) mean center, 2) average over genes, 3) Z-score. The description seems a little bit confusing to me and I want an exact example.

Here is a dataframe. How can I calculate the signature score for these two samples (a score for each column) separately based on the method described above?

```
        Sample1   Sample2
Gene1 0.3019117 0.3649211
Gene2 0.2861431 0.3072168
Gene3 0.3794475 0.6505417
Gene4 0.2794465 0.3906110
Gene5 0.3334156 0.5845917
Gene6 0.3513268 0.6560779
```

**data**

```
structure(list(Sample1 = c(0.301911734515308, 0.286143128965312, 
                                    0.379447523688471, 0.279446490938859, 0.333415615105398, 0.351326812590339
), Sample2 = c(0.36492108146509, 0.307216787356549, 0.650541715557005, 
                       0.390610992781682, 0.584591653411763, 0.656077880562312)), row.names = c("Gene1", 
                                                                                                "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", "Gene6"
                       ), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: does the below work for you? @lin Caijin?

Answer (score 0):

It's not super clear. I assume:

1. is just the mean of each sample
2. Is the rowwise mean of each gene
3. is the z score of each sample

If true, then the below does it:

```
#assume mean center is mean of each sample and z score
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),
               list(mean=mean,
                    z_score=scale),
                .names ="{.fn}_{.col}"))
#sample level mean
df <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(gene_mean=mean(c_across(1:2)))
```